# How to pass variables to another php file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parameter-passing

I have a PHP file "login.php" That is being called in a html using a js but the elements doesnt pass the variables to another php file "ucheck_com.php" Where it will perform the validations etc. is there an alternative way to do this?

sample.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="displaylogin"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
$("#displaylogin").load("user/login.php");
});
});
</script>
```

login.php:

```
<?php 
require_once 'userphp/connect.php'; 
require_once 'userphp/ucheck_com.php';
require_once 'userphp/errors.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en-US">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-container">
<form action="" method="post" class="main">
<label>Alias</label>
<input type="text" name="alias" value="">
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br />
<input type="submit" name="login_user" id="login_user" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ucheck_com.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
$alias = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['alias']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['password']);
$_SESSION['alias'] = $alias;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
if (empty($_SESSION['alias'])) {
array_push($errors, "Alias is required");
}
if (empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}
if(count($errors) == 0) {
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `alias` = '$alias' AND `password` = '$password'");
foreach ($result as $item) {
$_SESSION['email_add'] = $item['email_add'];
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $item['user_id'];
}
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row_cnt == 1) {
header("location: ../index.html");
} else {
array_push($errors, "Wrong alias/password combination");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$_SESSION` you need to open the session in the following manner:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: i have declared the session_start(); before the if statement but it still doesnt pass the variables..

i declared it like this:
<?php
session_start();
$alias = "";
$password="";
 
//if statement
?>